# Deletion of a Glib dispatcher (in the gtk thread as well) causes segfault

Tags: gnome, glib, gtkmm, gtk2

I have some multithread code where I use dispatchers. I was carefull in making the dispatchers created / destroyed in the gtk thread. However, its seems that they cannot be destroyed even from there. Please see this code (which is even single thread).
Am I missing something?

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HelloWorld:public Gtk::Window {
 public:

 Glib::Dispatcher* disp;
 Glib::Dispatcher disp2;
sigc::connection conn;

 void onDisp(){
  cout << "Hello by disp" << endl;
}


 HelloWorld():m_button("Hello"),m_destr("Destr") {
  disp=new Glib::Dispatcher();
  conn=disp->connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&HelloWorld::onDisp));      
  disp2.connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&HelloWorld::on_work));

 m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&HelloWorld::on_button_clicked));
  m_destr.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&HelloWorld::on_destr_clicked));
  v.add(m_button);
  v.add(m_destr);
  add(v);
  show_all_children();
}


protected:

void on_work(){
 usleep(1*1E5);
}

void on_button_clicked(){

   for (size_t i=0;i<100;i++){
if (disp!=NULL){
  (*disp)();
}
disp2();
   }
 }

 void on_destr_clicked() {
   conn.disconnect();
   delete disp;
   disp=NULL;
 }

Gtk::Button m_button;
Gtk::Button m_destr;
Gtk::VBox v;


};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

 HelloWorld helloworld;
//Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
 Gtk::Main::run(helloworld);

 return 0;
}
```

===ENVIRONMENT===
Ubuntu 11.10, gtkmm 2.24.2-1, libglib 2.30.0

===GDB====

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff70f6ee9 in Glib::DispatchNotifier::pipe_io_handler(Glib::IOCondition) () from /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff70f6ee9 in Glib::DispatchNotifier::pipe_io_handler(Glib::IOCondition) () from /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff70f8dcc in Glib::IOSource::dispatch(sigc::slot_base*) () from /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff70f89df in Glib::Source::dispatch_vfunc(_GSource*, int (*)(void*), void*) () from /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff4e68a5d in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff4e69258 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff4e69792 in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff5751db7 in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff7824326 in Gtk::Main::run(Gtk::Window&) () from /usr/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1
#8  0x0000000000442f9a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe368) at gtkmmWindow.cpp:66
```

====VALGRIND====

```
 Invalid read of size 8
==5254==    at 0x5931E81:
Glib::DispatchNotifier::pipe_io_handler(Glib::IOCondition) (in
/usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0)
==5254==    by 0x5933DCB: Glib::IOSource::dispatch(sigc::slot_base*) (in
/usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0)
==5254==    by 0x59339DE: Glib::Source::dispatch_vfunc(_GSource*, int
(*)(void*), void*) (in /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0)
==5254==    by 0x7B35A5C: g_main_context_dispatch (in
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x7B36257: ??? (in
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x7B36791: g_main_loop_run (in
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x70E6DB6: gtk_main (in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.6)
==5254==    by 0x530B325: Gtk::Main::run(Gtk::Window&) (in
/usr/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.so.1.1.0)
==5254==    by 0x442F99: main (gtkmmWindow.cpp:66)
==5254==  Address 0xd1ad9e8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==5254==    at 0x4C27FF2: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==5254==    by 0x5B584E8: sigc::signal_base::~signal_base() (in
/usr/lib/libsigc-2.0.so.0.0.0)
==5254==    by 0x443A45: HelloWorld::on_destr_clicked() (gtkmmWindow.cpp:50)
==5254==    by 0x4442B4: sigc::bound_mem_functor0<void,
HelloWorld>::operator()() const (in
/home/fabio/research/software/bin/gui/gtkmmWindow.greenplanet)
==5254==    by 0x4441DF: sigc::adaptor_functor<sigc::bound_mem_functor0<void,
HelloWorld> >::operator()() const (adaptor_trait.h:251)
==5254==    by 0x444096:
sigc::internal::slot_call0<sigc::bound_mem_functor0<void, HelloWorld>,
void>::call_it(sigc::internal::slot_rep*) (slot.h:103)
==5254==    by 0x5938B07:
Glib::SignalProxyNormal::slot0_void_callback(_GObject*, void*) (in
/usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0)
==5254==    by 0x78AF0A3: g_closure_invoke (in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x78C11F4: ??? (in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x78CA6B0: g_signal_emit_valist (in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x78CA851: g_signal_emit (in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==5254==    by 0x7040904: ??? (in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.6)
```

Comment: The field conn is never assigned.  It looks like you do, but you actually assign a temporary called 'conn'.  Did you actually crash on the conn.disconnect() line, perhaps?

Comment: @ergosys thank you,however that was not the problem

Comment: I'm unable to get the crash in either case, now that I've tried the code (thanks for compilable code, btw). This was on Mint LMDE and true for either gtk 2.4 or 3.0.  Can you provide a backtrace and platform information?

Comment: Nearly the same environment. I added the output from gdb and valgrind

Comment: Sorry, I didn't hit the Destr button while I was still getting output.  I get a crash when I do that (for either version).

Comment: This patch might be relevant: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2012-April/msg02237.html

Comment: @ergosys: sorry for the late reply, I solved by having a single static dispatcher, and some dynamical structure on my own, because I needed to make the code work with libs installed from apt-get, however, that really seems to be the point, thank you!